# How to append a string to the first column of a matrix file?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a matrix file as follows. 
The first column is a name list.
I want to add `_i1` to the end of each name.

```
        A1A A1B A1C A1D A1E 
TR6764_c0_g2    0.00    0.02    0.00    0.00    0.00   
TR25644_c0_g1   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   
TR4897_c0_g1    58.50   177.26  130.35  8.52    102.66  
TR900_c0_g2     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

The desired result is like this:

```
   A1A A1B A1C A1D A1E
TR6764_c0_g2_i1    0.00    0.02    0.00    0.00    0.00   
TR25644_c0_g1_i1   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   
TR4897_c0_g1_i1    58.50   177.26  130.35  8.52    102.66  
TR900_c0_g2_i1     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{$1=$1"_i1"}1;' test.txt 
        A1A A1B A1C A1D A1E 
TR6764_c0_g2_i1 0.00 0.02 0.00 0.00 0.00
TR25644_c0_g1_i1 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
TR4897_c0_g1_i1 58.50 177.26 130.35 8.52 102.66
TR900_c0_g2_i1 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
```

Or, if you need to keep the whitespace unchanged, perl:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\s/_i1$&/ if $.>1' test.txt 
        A1A A1B A1C A1D A1E 
TR6764_c0_g2_i1    0.00    0.02    0.00    0.00    0.00   
TR25644_c0_g1_i1   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   
TR4897_c0_g1_i1    58.50   177.26  130.35  8.52    102.66  
TR900_c0_g2_i1     0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Comment: Hey tendon, thanks for helping! I tried both of them and they all worked. I was gonna tell the white space was in front of the _g1 after I ran the perl command and I found you edited it, hahaha. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Bei yes, sorry, I had missed that :). By the way, if this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Just did. New to this forum and new to unix lol  Thanks for helping and reminding me that!

Answer (score -1):

I thought I'd match that first whitespace:

```
 sed 's/\s/_i1\t/' test.txt
```

Comment: What if it's not a space? In fact, that looks like it's likely to be a tab. Also, there's no need to escape the `_`, it has no special meaning. another problem is that this will also add a `_i1` to the first line.

Comment: The downvote was not mine, by the way. It was automatically cast by the system because a low quality flag was raised against this post (happens automatically for posts under a certain length) and because I edited to correct the I -> I, the system assumes that means the flag was valid and casts an automatic downvote. Yes, I know, the system can be kind of hard to understand until you get used to it :)

Comment: it was a space before you edited it. fishy ... !

Comment: Heh, I didn't touch it. I only used the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to fix it. Your edit will work for GNU `sed` (the `\s` is not recognized by other sed implementations), but you're still adding the `_i1` to the first line as well.

Comment: Hey infinite-etcetera, I tried your command and it did add to _i1 to the first line. I really appreciated your interest and quick reply! Hope you have a great rest of the day!